# Angularjs + Nodejs server response slow

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am developing a website using AngularJS and NodeJS+Mysql on the server. The client makes many http calls but nodeJS and Sequelize seems to be quite slow. What should I do on both client and server to speed up the response time and rendering of my data?

Answer (score 0):

Please give a demo code lines, It may be one of two possibilities for now - 
1. You can refine your sql-queries
2. I used to see people make a database connection on every request that makes it too slow to response

Comment: I use sequelize for making query. It's possible is it slow?

Answer (score 0):

You may be blocking nodejs. nodejs is single threaded. Ensure that you are using Asynchronous IO